# How can I monitor my phone usage between two top up

Tags: calls, data-monitoring

I have a prepaid mobile subscription and I want to know how much I phoned between two payments. There are plenty of applications that can track my phone usage in general, but I am missing the feature to specify which days I paid my bills. Is there any such thing?

Comment: What version of Android? That capability is built in to 4.0 (ICS) onwards.

Comment: I am using android 2.2

Comment: Have you tried searching the Play Store for "[prepaid](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=prepaid&c=apps)"? I see a number of possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [aPhoneMeTiX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rachittechnology.aPhoneMeTiX) completely offline phone usage analyzer. Generates graphs and reports which you can share easily.

PS - I'm creator of this application.

Comment: What's your affiliation with this app?

Comment: @DanHulme - I have updated my answer. Thanks for your comments

Comment: Thanks, it is a nice app and does exactly what I need! (The design is a bit unnatural for an android app, but it can easly get used to)

Comment: Thanks Peter. Your feedback is appreciated and glad you liked our app. We will be soon releasing app with facility to monitor data usage ( 3g, wireless etc ). Any other feature that you liked/disliked or see in future?

Comment: We have launched "Phone Usage Monitor" advance version of aphonemetix. That allows user to monitor 3g as well as data. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rachittechnology.PhoneUsageMonitor

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find such a feature shipping with Android itself -- but: Yes, there is. Or rather: there are. Plenty. It would become a long list. Watch out on the Playstore for [DroidStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nitro.phonestats) or [Call Meter 3G](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ub0r.android.callmeter) -- both apps allow you to specify the "payment day" (*DroidStats* is probably easier to use, while *Call Meter* can cover more complex scenarios).

There are also others like e.g. [PhoneUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jupiterapps.phoneusage), and more (you can follow the related apps for more suggestions).

Comment: I tried these apps, and the problem is that neither of them support prepaid plans. I can set my billing day, but for a prepaid, there is no such thing... What I would really need is a simple app that keeps track of how much I paid and since how much I used my phone

Comment: You didn't specify that part (though I should have guessed it from the word "prepaid", sorry). In that case, I don't know a perfect solution.

Comment: hmm... looks like the perfect next hobby project for me to create one... :) thanks anyways

Comment: If you cannot find it, make it -- yeah, many of my programs started out that way. Good choice -- and good luck!